# CMD.Connection association issue - object error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Why am I throwing an object not specified to an instance of an object ref error on this line:

```
CMD.Connection = connection;
```

For this code:

```
public static int EstablishDBConnection(String strCommandText, SqlConnection connection, DataTable DT = null, String[,] aryParameters = null, SqlDbType[] oAryType = null, bool DoesReturnData = true, int intTimeout = 3600, int intCommandType = 4)
{
    SqlCommand CMD = null;
    SqlDataAdapter DA = null;
    int intUbound = 0; //stores max ary size
    int returnVal = 0;

    try
    {
        //Set up our connection
        CMD.Connection = connection;
```

I have this working in a .net solution, but under my ASP.NET project it is triggering this error.  I'm passing this for the caller:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Reports"].ConnectionString);
Library.Utility.DB.Connection.EstablishDBConnection("usp_get_toolsweb_securitylvl",connection , dtSecurity, aryParameters, oAryType);
```

And this is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Reports" connectionString="Server=someserver\dev;uid=username;pwd=password;Database=Reports" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I confirmed by my immediate window that the connection string is passing correctly and populating from the passed in parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a SqlCommand instance before using it.

ie. change

```
SqlCommand CMD = null;
```

to

```
SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new instance of `SqlCommand` and assigns it to the variable `CMD` before setting `CMD.Connection`:

```
SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand();
```

Then:

```
CMD.Connection = connection;
```

`SqlCommand CMD = null;` just assigns null to a reference `CMD`.